# After dismissModalViewControllerAnimated the parent view is set to fullscreen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

After every dismiss off a ModalViewController the parent view is set to fullscreen. Why?

```
Before                After
+----------------+   +------------------+
|head            |   | detailview       |
+----------------+   |                  |
|detailview      |   |                  |
|                |   |                  |
|                |   |                  |
|                |   |                  |
+----------------+   +------------------+
```

**I created a "simple" sample project where the error appear.**

**http://github.com/rphl/modalTest**

Please take a look at it.

Comment: Was it the intent that this sample actually build?  It is missing MFMailComposeViewController if so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess, but an educated guess after having played around with your code a bit.

When you present a modal view it is added as a subview of the view belonging to the controller on which `presentModalViewController` was called.  Since the modal view is intended to be displayed full screen it would appear as though internally the frame of the superview is being made full screen.

I put the following in your MyDetailViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
}
```

Which resulted in the following output:

```
2010-09-19 00:23:51.823 ModalTest[2478:207] {{0, 164}, {320, 316}}
2010-09-19 00:23:56.178 ModalTest[2478:207] {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
```

The first line was output when the detail first appeared. The second line was output when the modal view was dismissed.

Now I actually don't particularly like the solution I found, but this has the desired affect.  In your `sendMail` method:

```
ModalTestAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.viewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And in your `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResulterror:` method:

```
ModalTestAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Basically this has the effect of making sure it's the full screen view holding the main UI of your application that presents the full screen modal view.  I don't think it's ideal however because I'm not a huge fan of deep parts of the code reaching up into the app delegate like that.

Comment: Ty for the solution, it works. If I find more time, I try to redesign the app, so i dont need to use the deep delegate. (i'm new at iphone dev)

Answer (score 5):

Something that works for me was to restore the frame after the modal view controller is dismissed. Code example:

### Presenting Modal View Controller

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.modalViewController animated:YES];
```

### Dismissing Modal View Controller

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
[self.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.view.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after preparing my iPhone app for iPad. It turned out to be something very strange and it took me hours to find it. It had to do with autorotation.

For:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
```

I was returning No

Previously I was returning:

```
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

For some reason, returning No caused the navigation bar to be underneath the status bar after dismissing a modal view controller.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked a long time ago but I would like to help others by sharing my experience, because it took me a while to figure it out.

I have a controller which is pushed in a navigation controller, which itself is the first tab in a `UITabBarController`. From my controller I present a modal view controller which plays fullscreen video using `MPMoviePlayerController`. When the video ends I close the modal view controller programmatically and return to the previous screen. But sometimes after the dismissal the status bar disappeared and the navigation bar was resized to take the status bar's space. Other times the navigation bar was half clipped and looking as if it underlaps the status bar.

This behavior was noticed in most of the cases, but not always, which made it very confusing. I've tried many things that other people here on StackOverflow suggest, among which was explicitly hiding the status bar in `viewWillAppear:`, returning `YES` for at least one orientation in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, presenting the modal view controller from the navigation controller or even the tabBar controller (which is the root view controller of my window), dismissing from a protocol method instead of calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` directly from the modal view controller, playing with `MPMoviePlayerController` notifications and states. Nothing seemed to help.

At the end I realized that my problems were only occurring when the video ended and the video controls (including the status bar) were hidden. I suppose that because my modal view controller is fullscreen (has its `wantsFullScreenLayout` property set to `YES`) and is presented from a view controller inside a navigation controller and a tabBar controller, when the status bar is hidden at the moment of the dismissal, this forces the navigation controller to resize it's child view controller and fill the screen, hiding the status bar or underlapping it. I was actually able to see this by logging the size of my DetailsViewController (the one that is pushed inside the navigation controller).

So, I did the most intuitive thing - I explicitly showed the status bar right before dismissing the modal view controller. This solved it completely and now my code looks like this:

**1. Presenting the modal view controller from the DetailsViewController**

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

**2. Dismissing the modal view controller from itself**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];  
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```